# SpringMVC : view not found 404 error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Here is the folder structure

[image]

here is the Controller part , which i am able to hit

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class ControllerClass
{
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ControllerClass.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView callRequest()
    {
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC";
        return new ModelAndView("index", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Here is my servlet part

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.java.learn.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
```

and this is my web.xml

```
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Learn</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Learn</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

i tried to add the url pattern as * but then i am not able to hit the controller.
also in the servlet part i removed web-inf/jsp as i move my index.html in webapps folder.

with this code i am able to hit the controller but when i return the view as "index" view didn't get rendered.

Comment: Have you added the configuration for spring to scan the packages where your controller is? Check this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm) and just repeat the tutorial on your project.

Comment: yeah i have added it , i can hit the controller with this code ..

Comment: Hit with what? Please be more clear, is your problem with the usage of `/*` in your servlet url pattern? What works, and what doesn't work?

Comment: i can hit the controller with the above code , but after that index.html didn't render

Comment: Your code looks alright, how is it not rendered? Do you get an error message, or an empty html page? Check the source code of the page, is it your `index.html` ?

Comment: no this is not my index.html ; it's 404 error

Comment: Why not mention that detail in your question?... (your title says not found, but still very vague isn't it?) Can you debug within your controller and try to see what is the error that maps to 404? I cannot find any issues with the details you've given.

Comment: now you have 2 view resolvers

Comment: that was a copy paste issue , not in the actual code

Comment: now i have made some changes, everytime i send the request

Comment: i am facing 
Apr 09, 2017 8:33:03 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Practice/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Learn'

Answer (score 0):

isn't it?

```
       <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Learn</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>

Comment: maybe you dont need that prefix

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String callRequest(ModelMap model){
  model.put("message", message);
  return "index";
 }

Comment: nopes :(

still can hit the controller, but no view render :(

Comment: try to move the views to that folder

Comment: <property name="prefix">
             <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
         </property>

Comment: in the class declaration you dont need @RequestMapping

Comment: @Controller
public class ControllerClass
{

Comment: you should have also in your servlet part - 
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

Comment: how do you try to hit the controller? and you already did it once?